# UIButton simple app - error in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

My iPhone app is quite simple, however it errors out. My app delegate opens up this view controller:

```
#import "Launch.h"

@implementation Launch

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    //image.image = img;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

which is just a red screen with a button. When I click the button, the app errors out with no error message. Why?

here is my main.m method, and when the program errors out, it points to the "return" line and indicates an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in a thread.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "testAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([testAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: the backtrace has no useful information. it just points to the main.m class and has no useful error message.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `NSLog()` in `buttonPressed`.

Comment: Like I said, there is no error message. The last thing I see on my console is: Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: BTW, `NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");` really should be: `NSLog(@"%s", Button Pressed!);`. `NSLog` expects a format string as its first parameter.

Comment: when I change it to NSLog(@"%s","Button Pressed!") now I get an error in the console: 2012-01-15 21:54:17.182 PhotoRandomizer[42135:f803] -[__NSCFString buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9037130
2012-01-15 21:54:17.183 PhotoRandomizer[42135:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9037130'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: There's no problem in using `NSLog(@"Button Pressed!")`, as `@"Button Pressed!"` is a perfectly legitimate format string, that takes no arguments.

Comment: Your code works for me.. Maybe your problem it's not in this code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target class has been deallocated, it needs to be retained.

From the Apple docs:

`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

> When you call this method, target is not retained.

You need to insure the class instance is retained.

Comment: The class seems to be the ViewController. It is instantiated somewhere and needs to be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

`@selector(buttonPressed:) //add the :`

and use this:

`-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;`

The button is asking for an action.

Comment: That is not required on iOS, iOS accepts three forms of target methods: with no parameters, a sender only or a sender and event. As an aside: MacOS does not have this flexibility.

Comment: OH,UH I made a boo boo, you are correct, the parameters are optional in iOS. Actually his code works, it must be something else...